# Abstraction in Typescript Indexed Access Types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type generated for me by a generator I cannot control, that is, I can't edit the source where `Foo` is defined:

```
type Foo = {
  foo1: { bar : { quux : string }},
  foo2: { bar: { quux: number }}
}
```

Then I use it in my code (which I can control):

```
function aaa(x: Foo["foo1"]["bar"]["quux"]) {
   ...
}

function bbb(x: Foo["foo2"]["bar"]["quux"]) {
   ...
}
```

There is a repetition of ["bar"]["quux"]. How can I avoid it?

One option would be to declare a mapped type:

```
type FooShort = {
  [p in keyof Foo]: Foo[p]["bar"]["quux"]
}

function aaa(x: FooShort["foo1"]) {
   ...
}

function bbb(x: FooShort["foo2"]) {
   ...
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

**Upd:** thanks to the comments, it turned out that my minimal example did work. But in my full code `Foo` is non-uniform:

```
type Foo = {
  foo1: { bar : { quux : string }},
  foo2: { bar: { quux: number }}
  foo3: number
}
```

Fortunately the `extends` trick proposed by @vera works as a conditional type (as described in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html after "However, what if we wanted MessageOf to take any type").

So if @vera adapts the code to use the conditional, so that BQ["foo1"] works with the Foo above, I'll accept that as the answer. If not, I'll have to answer my own question and mention @vera's contribution that let me find the solution myself.

Comment: Your mapped type solution works fine bro !

Comment: The obvious one would be to use a generic type: https://tsplay.dev/mp8VBm - but I think your mapped type is cleaner.

Comment: It's not clear why you can't simply alias those types

Comment: I ended up having 42 aliases like this  `export type IRefundStatusResponse = validationOperations['refundStatus']['responses']['default']['content']['application/json']` differing in only minor details